# Fatal error when rendering ggplot in shinydashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm having a R fatal error (bombshell -> Restart Session) when rendering a ggplot in a shinydashboard. The render of the basic `hist` plot works just fine, but with ggplot, it starts rendering the dashboard, then the slider box, an empty box for where the ggplot is supposed to be and then crashed.

Here is the code of the app I'm trying to render, slightly modified from [shinydashboard tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html):

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
        fluidRow(
            box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
            box(
                title = "Controls",
                sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    set.seed(122)
    histdata <- rnorm(500)
    
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        data <- data.frame(y = histdata[seq_len(input$slider)])
        ggplot(data, aes(x=y)) + geom_histogram()
        #hist(data$y)
        
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried adding `library(Cairo)` without success. BTW, ggplot works well in my non-shiny Rstudio environment. Here is my session info:

```
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
 os       Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS          
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio                     
 language en_AU:en                    
 collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_AU.UTF-8                 
 tz       Australia/Hobart            
 date     2021-09-22                  

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package        * version date       lib source        
 assertthat       0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 bslib            0.3.0   2021-09-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 cachem           1.0.6   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 Cairo            1.5-12  2020-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 callr            3.7.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 cli              3.0.1   2021-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 colorspace       2.0-2   2021-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 crayon           1.4.1   2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 DBI              1.1.1   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 desc             1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 devtools         2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 digest           0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 dplyr            1.0.7   2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 ellipsis         0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 evaluate         0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 fansi            0.5.0   2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 fastmap          1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 fs               1.4.1   2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 generics         0.1.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 ggplot2        * 3.3.5   2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 glue             1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 gtable           0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 htmltools        0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 httpuv           1.5.4   2020-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 jquerylib        0.1.4   2021-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 jsonlite         1.7.2   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 knitr            1.33    2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 later            1.1.0.1 2020-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 lifecycle        1.0.0   2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 magrittr         2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 memoise          1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 mime             0.11    2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 munsell          0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 pillar           1.6.2   2021-07-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 pkgbuild         1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgconfig        2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 pkgload          1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 prettyunits      1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 processx         3.5.2   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 promises         1.1.1   2020-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 ps               1.6.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 purrr            0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 R6               2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 Rcpp             1.0.7   2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 remotes          2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 rlang            0.4.11  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 rmarkdown        2.11    2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 rprojroot        2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 rsconnect        0.8.16  2019-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rstudioapi       0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 sass             0.4.0   2021-05-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 scales           1.1.1   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 sessioninfo      1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 shiny          * 1.6.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 shinydashboard * 0.7.1   2018-10-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 testthat         3.0.1   2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 tibble           3.1.4   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 tidyselect       1.1.1   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 usethis          2.0.1   2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 utf8             1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 vctrs            0.3.8   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 withr            2.4.2   2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 xfun             0.25    2021-08-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 xtable           1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 yaml             2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)

[1] /home/xxxxxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
[2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
[3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
[4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, EKS

Comment: Your code works fine for me - on windows.

Comment: Also works for me after adding `library(shiny)` on MacOS. Maybe try open in browser after you launch the app.

Comment: Thanks to all. I suspect that the problem could be related to a missing library in my ubuntu system. I wonder if someone has experienced something similar. I updated most of the R packages but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its an issue with the `geom_histogram()`, try adding bins to it

```
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$slider)
    data <- data.frame(y = histdata[seq_len(input$slider)])
    ggplot(data, aes(x=y)) + geom_histogram(bins=30)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks!. I tried you suggestion and still not working. In fact, it does not work with any ggplot geoms

Comment: I've tested this on my own shiny server, all is working fine, using `shiny1.6`

Comment: Thanks @Pork-Chop. Would you be able to post your session info to see if it is an issue with a package on my side, or compare it with the session info I posted in the original post.

Comment: Can u have a look what the logs are printing, they should be at `/var/log/shiny-server.log`